# How to save javascript variable values in a textfile?

Tags: javascript, python, json, html

I am trying to save the pixel values of an image on canvas. I have written a code to extract pixel values of the location clicked (on image). I want to save the values of the r,g,b into a text file for using them in the server side processing which is done in python flask.

```js
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var canvasColor = context.getImageData(x, y, 1,1); // rgba e [0,255]
    var pixels = canvasColor.data;
    var r = pixels[0];
    var g = pixels[1];
    var b = pixels[2];
    // i want to save r,g,b values in a text file for usage in the flask backend
}
```

```html
<script type = "text/javascript" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js"></script>
<label>Image File:</label><br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: as per my experience you can not save anything over server from javascript only 
You need to make some service over server side which can store Value provided from javascript(client)

Comment: and if you want to store local then use COOKIES  or
 **browser local variable **

Comment: You need to use ajax and server side script.

Comment: can you tell me how to write the server side script for this in flask. I am really new in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function like:

```
canvas.onclick = function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var canvasColor = context.getImageData(x, y, 1,1); // rgba e [0,255]
    var pixels = canvasColor.data;
    var r = pixels[0];
    var g = pixels[1];
    var b = pixels[2];
    // i want to save r,g,b values in a text file for usage in the flask backend

    //asign rgb values to the input
    document.getElementById('imageLoader').value = r + ',' + g + ',' + b;
}
```

And then send with Ajax o with an usual form (submit button) and save in a text file.

Comment: my function is not working. here is the code that i have written